# Manually Specifying Columns While Pivoting Tables?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have this data in R:

```
df<-data.frame(GROUP = c("A", "B", "C"),
               CLASS_1_1 = c(20, 60, 82),
               CLASS_2_1 = c(37, 22, 8),
               CLASS_1_2 = c(15,100,76),
               CLASS_2_2 = c(84, 18,88))

  GROUP CLASS_1_1 CLASS_2_1 CLASS_1_2 CLASS_2_2
1     A        20        37        15        84
2     B        60        22       100        18
3     C        82         8        76        88
```

I am using this code (from an answer provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/users/13203841/stats-noob) to pivot the data:

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(df, -GROUP, 
             names_pattern = "(CLASS_.*)_(.*)", 
             names_to = c(".value", "Date"))

# A tibble: 6 x 4
  GROUP Date  CLASS_1 CLASS_2
  <chr> <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 A     1          20      37
2 A     2          15      84
3 B     1          60      22
4 B     2         100      18
5 C     1          82       8
6 C     2          76      88
```

**Is there some way I can do this without using "names_pattern" and just manually specify the names?**

The reason that I am bringing this up is because in instances where the columns do not have a similar naming structure, I feel it would be easier to manually specify columns (e.g. `colnames(df)` and then manually copy and paste the results of this statement, or to just reference these columns by `d[,c(2,3,4,5)` )

As an example:

```
#pseudocode - does not work : OPTION 1

pivot_longer(df, -GROUP, 
             names_pattern = "c(CLASS_1_1, CLASS_2_1, CLASS_1_2, CLASS_2_2)", 
             names_to = c(".value", "Date"))

#pseudocode - does not work : OPTION 2

pivot_longer(df, -GROUP, 
             names_pattern = "df[,c(2,3,4,5)]", 
             names_to = c(".value", "Date"))
```

Anyone know?

Thanks!!

Comment: Yes, look at the help page `?pivot_longer` you can see the arguments and some examples. The first 2 examples both don't use `names_pattern`. But with multiple `names_to`, you need to specify either `names_to` or `names_pattern`. It's how R tells the difference between the `value` part and the `date` part.

Comment: @GregorThomas, I'm inferring that OP wants the power of grouping columns together, but in a way that regex does not (easily) empower. stats_noob, perhaps you can provide an unambiguous and representative example that doesn't allow an easy-out with simple regex? (The resolution might still use `names_pattern=`, I don't know, but it'll be much easier to inform that with a different data sample.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to type out the names, use a separator that `names_sep` can pick out easily and rename the wide columns before the pivot, something like this:

```
first_part = c("Class_1", "Class_2", "Class_1", "Class_2")
second_part = c(1, 1, 2, 2)

first_part = c("Class_1", "Class_2", "Class_1", "Class_2")
second_part = c(1, 1, 2, 2)
names(df)[2:5] = paste(first_part, second_part, sep = "|")
pivot_longer(df, -GROUP, 
             names_sep = "\\|", # | is a special regex character so we escape it
             names_to = c(".value", "Date"))
# # A tibble: 6 × 4
#   GROUP Date  Class_1 Class_2
#   <chr> <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 A     1          20      37
# 2 A     2          15      84
# 3 B     1          60      22
# 4 B     2         100      18
# 5 C     1          82       8
# 6 C     2          76      88
```

Or in your original case you could give `name_sep` an integer that will be interpreted as a position, in your example the split is always at the 8th character, but that leaves us with a trailing `_` to clean up:

```
pivot_longer(df, -GROUP, 
             names_sep = 8,
             names_to = c(".value", "Date")) %>%
  rename_with(.fn = sub, pattern = "_$", replacement = "")
```

Or you could write a regex pattern to separate at the **last** `_`, though this is a more complicated regex pattern:

```
pivot_longer(df, -GROUP, 
             names_sep = "_(?=[^_]*$)",
             names_to = c(".value", "Date"))
```